# How to trigger circleci serverless.ts which is located in a sub-directory let's say /apps/api/work/

Tags: typescript, serverless, circleci, monorepo

I'm new in the circleci can you people please help me, I'm having typescript mono-repo and I want to deploy serverless from a specific path let say /apps/api/work/serverless.ts but in circleci it is giving an error stating

Cannot find "/home/circleci/apps/api/work/serverless.ts" in service folder

Please help.

I'm trying to build and deploy serverless.ts from /home/circleci/apps/api/work/serverless.ts path.